# Android Play Store market:// link is no longer working?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-play

I've been redirecting my users for the past year from my domain:

http://example.com/get

to: market://details?id=com.example.myapp

Today I've check this on Nexus 5/LG G3/OnePlus One from the chrome browser app and it stopped working!

Now, when my users try to download the app they are redirected to a broken link.

Anyone know anything about this change in the Chrome app in Android?

Comment: Works fine for me. Play Store ver. 5.1.11

Comment: What device did you use? It doesn't work with Nexus 5 5.0.1 with Google Play 5.1.11 and Chrome 40.0.2214.89. It does work with Samsung Galaxy Note 4 and Galaxy S4

Comment: Redirecting to a app that many don't want should come with a heavy penalty, it's time that this gets an end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from reading the chrome's version 40 release, there are some insight i d like to share
http://blog.chromium.org/2014/12/chrome-40-beta-powerful-offline-and.html

they updated to Content Security Policy Level 2, which has a stronger control over redirects.
https://w3c.github.io/webappsec/specs/content-security-policy/#changes-from-level-1

> 1. The path component of a source expression is now ignored if the resource being loaded is the result of a redirect, as described in §4.2.2.3 Paths and Redirects.
> 2. Redirects are blocked by default, and explicitly allowed with a new unsafe-redirect expression.

So I did some testing. if your initial action started from redirect (no matter window.location or http 302) it will show an error. but once i created a hyperlink to market:// and explicitly clicked it, it worked fine.

for now i ended up creating a webpage in between, where i ask the user to click the link to proceed.

Comment: Great advise, I'll check it out. So you say it's not a bug, they will not fix it in the future?

Comment: Thats what I am wondering too. But in your case my workaround should be able to solve the issue. just create page in example.com/get and you place a link on it. then it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is I need my customers to click another link, they already clicked on a link to download the app, and now another one. I feel this is a bad experience for my customers. For now I redirect to the mobile web play store

Comment: did you create a page for all of them? i do show that page only for chrome 40+. everything else is behaves like before. but your solution is also valid

Answer (score 6):

I was testing this url on different devices with different OS/Play Store/ Play Services/ Browsers. looks like it's related to browser but not OS or Play Services.

Initially I updated Play Services and Google Play Store and my old Chrome (v18) was opening `market://details?id=` url fine.

Afterward I had updated my Chrome (*v18*) to version **40**. And it's not working any more.

Meanwhile, FireFox and default "Browsers" still opens this url and redirects to Google Play Store app.

P.S. I have registered issue in Chromium bug tracker. Let's see if there will be any response:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&q=market&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&id=454396&thanks=454396&ts=1422888121

**UPDATE** [6.05.15] : Unfortunately, they decided not to fix this issue, saying, that it's planned behaviour. As they said, user should click the link by himself. Only then re-direct to the app on devices is allowed.

So, there is only one "work-around", that I see for now: create a page, that contains text like *"Click link below to go to the app"*, followed by link like:

`<a href="market://details?id=com.example.myapp"> Load Example App </a>`

or

`<a href="intent://foo.bar#Intent;scheme=blabla;package=com.example.myapp;end" > Load App/ Activate your Profile  </a>`

Comment: Thanks Alex, hope they fix it soon

Comment: what is `foo.bar`?

Answer (score 1):

Try the link below, replacing your.app.id with your own identifier:

```
https://play.app.goo.gl/?link=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.app.id&ddl=1&pcampaignid=web_ddl_1
```