# Cant open app link in android playstore from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want that when i load the html page, he will redirect to playstore app

the problem that i get playstore in chrome and not in android app

i  have tried this without success

> 1

```
<a id="androidLink" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mylink" target="_top"></a>

document.getElementById("androidLink").click();
```

> 2

```
window.location.href = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mylink";
```

> 3

```
header('location: mylink ')
```

> 4

```
window.location.href = "market://details?id=mylink";
```

Comment: Do you have your browser set to be the default app to open for market links? Check your default app settings

Comment: There is a mistake in target in your link : "targrt"

Comment: User has to click the link, Chrome ignores redirect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266051/android-play-store-market-link-is-no-longer-working

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51067917/1720332) : this is the link you should use to redirect on the PlayStore Application.