# "market" links are blocked

Tags: android, google-chrome

[Sample picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCCfJ.png)

When I open Google play in my Chrome browser, there is such a prompt.

> "market" links are blocked.

The process is like this：

1. Click the button on my webapp page
2. Open app through protocol，Jump to Onelink at the same time
3. Back my webapp page
4. Then the error show

My android chrome version is 101.0.4951.61，please help～

Comment: This thread may be help you- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266051/android-play-store-market-link-is-no-longer-working