# Open google play store to app page with html

Tags: html, google-play

My html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/main.js')}}"></script>

    <script>
        var devise = getMobileOperatingSystem();

        switch (devise) {
            case "Android":
                window.location.assign("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my_id");
                //window.location.assign("market://details?id=my-id");
                break;
            default:
                window.location.assign("https://www.my_website.com");
        };
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When I put url "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my_id", it opens play store in browser, and when I put "market://details?id=my-id", nothing happens. That's both options I saw on the internet. Any idea how I could do that please?

Comment: For security reasons, you are no longer allowed to do an internal redirect to a "market:" URL. It can only be clicked by the user. [Android Play Store market:// link is no longer working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28266051/android-play-store-market-link-is-no-longer-working)